# How to read line from txt?

Tags: java, file, io

How can I read line from text? Look at my code:

```
public static String getTemplateFromFile() {
        String name = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                        FileReader(
                      "http://localhost:8080/blog/resources/cache/templateName.txt"));
            name = reader.readLine();
            //name="TEST";
            //NULL anyway
            reader.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

        }


        return name;
    }
```

Also I have got secnod version, but my server freeze.

```
public static String getTemplateFromFile() {
        String name = null;
        /*
        try {
               URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/blog/resources/cache/templateName.txt");
               Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream());   

               name=s.nextLine();
               s.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {

               ex.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        return name;
    }
```

I think it can't close connection or something.
It returns me NULL even I say `name="TEST";` in try construction.

Comment: It's probably throwing an exception. Don't consume exceptions silently like that.

Comment: Possibly an Exception was thrown. Put something in your `catch` block, like `e.printStackException()` to see if it is the case.

Comment: Hm. Really. If I try this `catch (Exception e) {
   
   name="TEST";

  }` it will return "TEST".

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 6):

`FileReader` is exactly that – a class that reads from **files**, not HTTP requests.

You're getting an invalid file path exception, which you're then ignoring in your evil empty catch block.

Instead, you should use `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try{
     URL reader=new URL("http://localhost:8080/blog/resources/cache/templateName.txt");
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(reader.openStream()));
     name = br.readLine();
     //name="TEST";     
     br.close();
}catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

AFAIK, `URL#openStream()` internally calls `URL#openConnection()` which creates an instance of `URLConnection` and calls `URLConnection#getInputStream()` on it.

Comment: oh. I didn't notice. I'll try.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat and my console freeze after that.Don't know why.

Comment: first line. because it has only one line.

Comment: check if you are able to access your local file through a browser...just to make sure that Tomcat is hosting properly@JohnSmith